# How to click a link that has an SVG child using Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to click a button on a website using Selenium + Java, but am having no luck clicking this one particular button (I am able to click and type in other fields but this one in particular is giving me trouble).

This is what the HTML looks like and here is the image that I need to click:

```
<div class="sc-dIUggk XavQL">
   <a href="www.someWebsite.com" target="_top" name="tempo-reports-menu-item" class="sc-fbNXWD eXJbNH">
      <div class="sc-GTWni jPMpTI">
         <svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
            <g transform="translate(13 13)" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
               <rect stroke="#004976" stroke-width="1.5" fill-opacity="0.64" fill="#00D8F6" fill-rule="nonzero" x="0.75" y="0.75" width="20.5" height="20.5" rx="2"></rect>
               <rect fill="#004976" x="14" y="5" width="2" height="13" rx="0.5"></rect>
               <rect fill="#004976" x="10" y="12" width="2" height="6" rx="0.5"></rect>
               <rect fill="#004976" x="6" y="9" width="2" height="9" rx="0.5"></rect>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

[image: SVG]

This is the xpath I used to try to click `"//a[@name,'tempo-reports-menu-item']"`, and its used like this `driverexec.clickByXpath("Click Reports", "//a[@name,'tempo-reports-menu-item']");`

ClickByXpath() is just my backend code for clicking by xpath.

No matter what I do, either the element can't be found or can't be clicked.

EDIT-> I have also tried this xpath:

```
        driverexec.clickByXpath("Click Reports", "//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='rect']/ancestor::a[@name='tempo-reports-menu-item']");
```

If I search this xpath in the DOM, it is found but still cannot be clicked.

This is the error message:

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[name()='svg']//*[name()='rect']/ancestor::a[@name='tempo-reports-menu-item']
```

This is my function 'clickByXpath()`:

```
    public boolean clickByXpath(String description, String xpath) throws Exception {
        int retry = 0;
        while (retry <= maxAttempts) {
            try {
                delayFor(2500);
                driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)));
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
                delayFor(500);
                // System.out.println("clicked " + description);
                System.out.println("clicked " + description);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                retry++;
//              System.out.println("retrying click by xpath for row " + row + " with xpath " + xpath);
                if (retry > maxAttempts) {
                    System.out.println("now not retrying");
                    String message = "Could not click [" + description + "] with xpath " + xpath;
                    System.out.println("failed to click with error: " + e.getMessage());
                    failure(message);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML and properly format it instead.

Comment: You also need to post the full error message as text, properly formatted, in your question. We can't evaluate code that we can't see... you need to add the code for `.clickByXpath()`. Have you tested your locator in the browser using `$x()`?

Comment: Okay I added the HTML that belongs to the item I am trying to click. I am not sure what you mean by the `$x()` ? I can control + F the HTML after inspecting it and paste in the Xpath in my question and it gets highlighted yellow in the HTML but nothing happens if I surround the xpath with $x()

Comment: Nevermind I see what you mean, Yes, if I use $x() then i get one element returned in the console

Comment: //a[@name='tempo-reports-menu-item']//*[name()='svg'] try this

Comment: Still the same error unfortunately @YaDavMaNish

Comment: What does it contains `clickByXpath()` ? we need to see the internal implementation. I see quite often now that wrapper method are more complex than actual raw selenium methods.

Comment: It is definitely more complex but that is because we use this backend for many other sites and projects that take longer than they should to load. I added it to my question though.

Comment: Can you share URL if it's public ? if it's private, can you share page source.

Comment: WebElement domElement = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
    .executeScript("return document.getElementsByTagName('svg')");
domElement.click();  can you check with this

Comment: I shared the relevant snippet of HTML. If it helps, the 'div' I shared in my question is nested within other divs but that shouldn't matter. There is only one element with the name='tempo-reports-menu-item'

Comment: Didnt work :/ @YaDavMaNish

Comment: code for clickByXpath() make sure that you don't face any StaleElementReferenceException but you need to have a more enhanced utility method to handle other things.

Comment: If I let the program run its course until it gets to the screen that has that button, I can manually click it no problem. But Selenium will not.

Comment: What is `driverWait` in `clickByXpath()` and why is it named differently than `driverexec` in your script. You need to use the same driver instance to wait.

Comment: A link to the page would make investigations infinitely easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to switch to the iFrame that contained the link I needed to click.

```
// Have to switch to the iFrame that contains the entire <body> first
        driverexec.switchToIframeById("io.tempo");
        driverexec.clickByXpath("Reports", "//*[@id='tempo-sidebar']//a[@name='tempo-reports-menu-item']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the below code which i have used with `Explicit Wait`.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[local-name()=\"svg\"]"))).click();
```

I will also recommend you to use `Actions` class for clicking. See if it helps

Do let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately I get this error: 
`element click intercepted: Element <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="presentation">...</svg> is not clickable at point (30, 28). Other element would receive the click: <span role="img" aria-label="Appswitcher Icon" class="css-1w1m1we">...</span>`